# How to save the current configuration of preferences?

Tags: stylesheet

When I go Edit -> Preferences -> Appearance there are many colors to set. I want to set them all non-default, but I too want to save the configuration and be able  to reload it, when needed.

My only idea is that it may be possible to modify preferences through code, but i have no idea how to figure the long names of each single color?!

I have win7, v10.0.2.0, 64-bit

Comment: If you are on windows, I think the preference is in `C:\Users\[your_user_name]\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\FrontEnd\init.m`